# NetShareEnum returns 1702

Tags: c#, unc

Im writing some software and i need to get the list of Network Shared Folders. I did all according to this article 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2939/Network-Shares-and-UNC-paths
and the method NetShareEnum returns 1702, and returns no folders.

The compiled sample from article works fine, I tried to dissasemble it througth Resharper but it is also returns 1702 result here:

```
protected static void EnumerateSharesNT(string server, ShareCollection shares)
{
    int dwLevel = 2;
    int hResume = 0;
    IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        int num2;
        int num3;
        **int num4 = NetShareEnum(server, dwLevel, out zero, -1, out num2, out num3, ref hResume);**
        if (5 == num4)
        {
            dwLevel = 1;
            num4 = NetShareEnum(server, dwLevel, out zero, -1, out num2, out num3, ref hResume);
        }
        if ((num4 == 0) && (num2 > 0))
        {
            Type t = (2 == dwLevel) ? typeof(SHARE_INFO_2) : typeof(SHARE_INFO_1);
            int num6 = Marshal.SizeOf(t);
            int num7 = 0;
            for (int i = zero.ToInt32(); num7 < num2; i += num6)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(i);
                if (1 == dwLevel)
                {
                    SHARE_INFO_1 share_info_ = (SHARE_INFO_1)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, t);
                    shares.Add(share_info_.NetName, string.Empty, share_info_.ShareType, share_info_.Remark);
                }
                else
                {
                    SHARE_INFO_2 share_info_2 = (SHARE_INFO_2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, t);
                    shares.Add(share_info_2.NetName, share_info_2.Path, share_info_2.ShareType, share_info_2.Remark);
                }
                num7++;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (IntPtr.Zero != zero)
        {
            NetApiBufferFree(zero);
        }
    }
}
```

server is input string for example "\192.168.1.69"

Comment: That specific error code means ["The binding handle is invalid."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681386(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: i know what does it mean. Where should i look for error? Why is it working in compiled sample from article, and is not working in my project?